# Searching for a specific JOB by the procedure it calls

Tags: oracle, jobs, database-table

Is it possible to search a JOB by the code it executes?
I.E. I want to find the JOB that launches a certain stored procedure.

Is there a query to do it?

[image]

Comment: there is a system view for the dbms_jobs. I currently don't know its name, but you should be able to find it pretty quick.

Comment: Is there a DBA_running_jobs table also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the all_dependencies view.

```
select * from all_dependencies where referenced_name = 'YOUR_STORED_PROC';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  * 
from 
  user_jobs 
where 
  what like '%my_token%';
```